# Mismatch of types for rtk-query-graphql-request and graphql-request

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Im trying to build rtk query api with GraphQL. But it seems there is a mismatch of types of packages between `@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query` and `graphql-request`
what I get as error as follows;

```
Type 'import("path/to/file/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index").GraphQLClient' is not assignable to type 'import("path/to/file/node_modules/@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index").GraphQLClient'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'url'.ts(2322)
```

and I get the error on `**client**` field of the `graphqlRequestBaseQuery` I tried to remove node_modules and reinstall, not worked unfortunately...

here is my `api.ts` ;

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { graphqlRequestBaseQuery } from '@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query'; 
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request';
import { gqlClient } from '../gql/gql-client';

 
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: graphqlRequestBaseQuery({ client: new GraphQLClient('http://localhost:4000/graphql') }), // error is at "client" field
  tagTypes: [],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: () => '/users',
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUsersQuery } = api;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before a while, this is due to version mismatch with `graphql-request` used in `@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query` and the one you installed manually.

So instead of passing `client` as instance of `GraphQLClient`, you can just pass a `url`, and the rest goes as before. The code looks something like this:

```
type E = {[k in 'name'|'message'|'response']:any};

const api = createApi({
...
 baseQuery: graphqlRequestBaseQuery<E>({
  url:'path-to-your-graphql-server',
  customErrors: (args)=>{
   /** modify the response of the error as you wish here,
   /* then return it.
   /* Ex:
   /* return {name:args.name, message:args.message, response: args.response}
   */
  }
 }),
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using @rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query version 2.2.0.

```
import { createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { graphqlRequestBaseQuery } from "@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query";
import { ClientError } from "graphql-request";

import { RootState } from "../store";

const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_TECHNOTES_API_HTTP_GRAPHQL;
const techNotesHttpAPI = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "http://localhost:4001/graphql";

const baseQuery = graphqlRequestBaseQuery<
  Partial<ClientError> & { statusCode: number; error: string }
>({
  url: techNotesHttpAPI,
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const state = getState() as RootState;
    const token = state.auth.token;

    if (token) {
      headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    }

    return headers;
  },
  customErrors: ({ name, stack, response }) => {
    const {
      message = "",
      statusCode = 500,
      error = "",
    } = response?.errors?.length
      ? response?.errors[0]?.extensions.response
      : {};

    return {
      name,
      message,
      statusCode,
      error,
      stack,
    };
  },
});

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ["User", "Note"],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Comment: Please provide details on why and how this answers the question

Comment: There are two options to deal with the error. (1) Downgrade to v4.3.0 from v5.0.0 of graphql-request, or (2) instead of using GraphQLClient, pass in the 'url' instead. Essentially, there is a mismatch in the GraphQLClient implementation in v5.0.0 of graphql-request.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while following the code-gen documentation. To add to what [@dwight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20532272/dwight) suggested, you can also just copy the code files for the [`@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/tree/master/packages/rtk-query-graphql-request-base-query/src) package and put them in your project. Import `graphqlRequestBaseQuery` from there.

`@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query` imports `GraphQLClient` from `graphql-request` internally and the type mismatch could be because the dependency has not been updated yet on the official repository.

hope this helps